# "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" while I am inserting on a many-to-many situation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

After reading similar issues I still did not managed to overcome this problem. What is interesting is that I decoupled and made a separate project and there it works.

I have two entities JobAnnouncement and Skill and they are in a many-to-many relationship. I am able to insert as long as I do not have any Skills added to the job announcement.

Let me put in the code:

```
public class JobAnnouncement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        //other properties
        public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    }

public class Skill
    {
//other properties
 public virtual ICollection<JobAnnouncement> JobAnnouncements { get; set; }
    }
```

The insertion code is (tried all ways including the dumb ones):

```
 public void AddJobAnnouncement(JobAnnouncement jobAnnouncemnet)
        {
_jobAnnouncement.Content = jobAnnouncemnet.Content; //ok
_jobAnnouncement.CompanyId = jobAnnouncemnet.CompanyId; //ok
 _jobAnnouncement.Skills = jobAnnouncemnet.Skills; //fails
db.JobAnnouncements.Add(_jobAnnouncement); //throws exception
            db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Just for your information I did override the SaveChanges() method (that is why I left the DateAdded. I don't think that's causing the error, I tryied removin it and it still doesn't work.)

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
        {
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("DateAdded") != null))
                {
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                    {
                        entry.Property("DateAdded").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                    }
    
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                    {
                        entry.Property("DateAdded").IsModified = false;
                    }
                }
    }
    }
```

Also, I am using Niject, and the instruction found on SO does not help:

`kernel.Bind<CareerTrackContext>().To<CareerTrackContext>().InRequestScope();`

I've even tried to alter the entity lifespan. The version of Entity Framework is 6.1.3 and I am using code first.

I just don't see the issue. What can I try next?

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix ... not necessarily a solution. The AddJobAnnouncement should look like this:

```
 public void AddJobAnnouncement(JobAnnouncement jobAnnouncemnet)
        {
_jobAnnouncement.Content = jobAnnouncemnet.Content; //ok
_jobAnnouncement.CompanyId = jobAnnouncemnet.CompanyId; //ok
 // it will by ok now
jobAnnouncement.Skills = new List<Skill>();
            foreach (var skill in jobAnnouncemnet.Skills)
            {
                _jobAnnouncement.Skills.Add(db.Skills.Find(skill.Id));
            }
}
```

Right now I don't even now why it works.